# HTML table with a percentage width, and a pixel limit

Tags: html, html-table

I've created a table with a width of 90% of the page, which is fine, unless the monitor is a widescreen - in which case, the items in the table are too spaced out. Is it possible to set a width of a table as the percentage of the page, but with a pixel width limit?
For example, a table that was 90% of the page, but had a limit of 1000px so it couldn't exceed that size.

```
<table align="center" style="width:90%;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: add max-width: 1000px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example code:

```
<table align="center" style="width:90%; max-width:1000px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css `max-width: 1000px`. Table with this will be no more bigger than 1000px.